# After creating a java application that uses mysql databases, what does the user's computer need in order to run it properly?

Tags: java, mysql, database

So I've been working in a program that will allow the user to view and manipulate a database. The UI is almost ready and soon I will create the connection to the database. I was wondering if the user will be able to run the distributable jar without having to install additional programs (such as sql server or so). I hope you guys can tell me that.

I still haven't fully decided if I will use the mysql database or a java DB from netbeans. I think I'll rather use mysql because there are many more tutorials for it and sincerely I know nothing about databases, I'll have a hard, but interesting time learning all that I need to get my program running. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that Java application can run without anything else that needs to be installed (except for Java, of course).

The app needs to include the JDBC driver for MySQL, which [may or may not be a licensing problem](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/02/17/when-are-you-required-to-have-a-commercial-mysql-license/). If you cannot ship it with your app, the user will have to download it separately.

In order to use the program, the user will need to have access to the database to view and manipulate. That is usually only possible over local intranet or VPN for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In case if your application access the database on some remote server - then you won't need to do anything but ship JAR file with appropriate JDBC driver with your application. This JAR file has to be added to classpath as well.

If the application access the database server on the same host as your program is running, then obviously there should be some database server installed (MySQL in the case). But if the application is dedicated to database administrators or somebody like that - then you still not need to worry about database presense - it will be there.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I got it all except the last sentence. What do you mean with "it will be there"? Thank you again.

Comment: I mean that database will be installed on client's host, so you don't need to worry about the installation/or ship database installer with your application.

Comment: Shipping the MySQL JDBC driver with your application may require a special license, though.

Comment: exactly. Used to be LGPL, but now you cannot ship the jar file with non-open-source software anymore (without a commercial license).

Comment: How could I get the license in case I require it? (will i?)

Comment: You don't need the license if you can instruct the user to download the jar file from the MySQL web site and where to put it for your program to find. You just cannot bundle it with your application unless it is open-source.

Comment: Oh, ok, that won't be a problem, I think. Thank you a lot.